# Error with Cloudy's make command on WSL2

Tags: compiling, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, make, compiler

I'm using a WSL2 (windows subsystem Linux) with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
I want to use the Cloudy package, a Linux based simulation tool https://gitlab.nublado.org/cloudy/cloudy
I have installed the package and tried to run the `make` command but I'm getting this error:

```
sh: 0: Illegal option --
Creating cloudyconfig.h
no object file found, is the compiler working?
make: *** [Makefile:255: /home/ray/cloudy_master/Cloudy_17/source/cloudyconfig.h] Error 1
```

The `gcc` and `make` packages seem up to date. I really don't understand the error. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: hello, Thank you for your reply. @NotTheDr01ds I did try installing g++ and the build-essential, but it kept giving me a chain of unmet dependencies. (libc6, libc-dev etc)

Answer (score 1):

You should install g++ (not gcc) to compile Cloudy

Comment: I'd recommend installing the `build-essential` package, but yes.

Comment: hello, Thank you for your reply. @Lushen @NotTheDr01ds
I did try installing `g++` and the `build-essential`, but it kept giving me a chain of unmet dependencies. (`libc6, libc-dev` etc)

Comment: @RayWilson Odd.  I installed a completely clean Ubuntu test instance on WSL, updated/upgrade packages, cloned the Cloudy repo, tried building, and experienced (among others) the `sh: 0: Illegal option --`.  All I did was install `build-essential` and then I was able to compile successfully.  I'll try to give it another shot later today to see if there's something I missed.